# Installing fonts on GUI-less Linux for wkhtmltoimage

Tags: linux, centos, fonts

I'm having difficulties getting `wkhtmltoimage` to recognize fonts not installed on my CentOS 5.8 box.

I've tried installing the font I need (Verdana) via `.rpm` but that didn't seem to work.

I tried various webfont embedding methods and that didn't work either.

Does anyone know if I need to have GUI software installed (X11, Gnome, etc.) to allow `wkhtmltoimage` to use the fonts installed on the OS?

The fonts installed by the `.rpm` are found in:

```
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdana.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanai.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanab.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore/verdanaz.ttf
```

---

Edit: Running fc-cache -f -v

```
/usr/share/fonts: caching, 0 fonts, 3 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera: caching, 10 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/default: caching, 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1: caching, 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript: caching, 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/msttcore: caching, 31 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/X11/fonts/OTF: skipping, no such directory
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I'm afraid wkhtmltoimage still doesn't use my Verdana font.

Comment: This should have happened automatically but try running `fc-cache -f -v`. If that fixes it, cool, if not, check whether your fonts appear in that command's output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've edited my original post to show the output. Unfortunately, despite the fonts being found by fc-cache, wkhtmltoimage still doesn't use them.

Comment: OK, please explain 1) exactly how you installed the fonts, the whole command please and 2) How you are trying to use them with wkhtmltoimage and how they fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just fixed it.

Please follow this way :

```
wget http://www.my-guides.net/en/images/stories/fedora12/msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
```

then it will show correct type of lots of fonts.

And don't forget , For Centos that has not GUI libraries  , You should install complete list of GUI libraries to get better results.